# How to use SCSS global variables and mixins in my React project?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I have this variable in my `global.scss` file:

`$orange: #ee6123;`

I want to use it in my component's stylesheet (in `header.scss`):

```
.header { background: $orange; }
```

The global stylesheet is located in `/static/css/global.scss` and the component stylesheet is located at `src/components/Header/index.scss`. The global stylesheet is included in my base `src/index.jsx` file. The component stylesheet is included in `src/components/Header/index.jsx`. Is there any way I can use the `$orange` variable in my component's stylesheet?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet